# Mistake in switching order of integration to find Area enclosed by $y=2-x$ and $y=x^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

edit1: i have forgotten to specify that i am interested only in the area enclosed in the first quadrant(ie both x and y are equal or bigger than zero)

$$ \int^{1}_{0}\int^{2-x}_{x^2}1 dydx= \frac{7}{6}  $$ but when i try to change the order of integration to  $$ \int^{2}_{0}\int^{2-y}_{sqrt(y)}1 dxdy  $$ i dont get the same solution and i have no idea where i am making the mistake since i think i swapped the limits corectly and square root function is well defined on the part im integrating and to me looks like im enclosing the same space. Thank you in advance

Comment: The first integral in the question differs from the area described in the title, because the integral covers only the part of the area to the right of the $y$-axis. The second integral gives the area of a very different region, a part outside the area described in the title minus another part inside. I'd recommend that you draw a good picture of the two graphs and of the area between them and then use that to correct the limits on your integrals.

Comment: @AndreasBlass im sorry i have forgotten to specify that i am interested only in the area enclosed in the first quadrant(ie both x and y are equal or bigger than zero), why doesnt my second double integral enclose the same area to the right of y-axis>

Comment: You should draw the region. For a fixed $y$, $x$ will start at $0$ and stop at one of the curves, but the curve it hits depends on what $y$ is. The upper boundary is the line, the lower boundary is the parabola. So you will necessarily have two integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate with respect to $x$ first, note that for a particular value of $y,x$ ranges from $0\to2-y$ when $1<y<2$ and $0\to\sqrt y$ when $0<y<1$, giving us the required integral:$$\left[\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt y}+\int_1^2\int_0^{2-y}\right]1~dx~dy$$

[image: Figure]

You may confirm that this gives $7/6$.

Comment: Yikes! That's terrible notation! (I understand what you mean, but that hurts to look at!) Still, +1 for the graph which tells the whole story nicely.